How can I determine the text direction for the main polyglossia language?
As a follow-up to this answer....
How can I find the text direction of the main document language? For instance I notice that using the \mainlanguagename macro does not work:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{urdu}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \langdir { m }
  {
    \prop_item:Nn \l_xpg_langsetup_prop { #1 / direction }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Without macro: \langdir{english}

With macro: \langdir{\mainlanguagename}

\end{document}

Produces:
Without macro: LR

With macro: 


\prop_item:No \l_xpg_langsetup_prop { #1 / direction } (the o will expand the macro once).
